# RaycastHit2D doesn't hit gameobjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
Vector2 pos = new Vector2(transform.position.x + 0.5f, transform.position.y);
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(pos, Vector2.right, 1f, 1 << 8);
Debug.DrawRay(pos, Vector2.right, Color.green, 1f);

if (hit.collider != null)
{
    Debug.Log(hit.collider.name);
}
```

The player's layer is number 8 and the gameobjects are number 9.

I want to detect a gameobject right by side of cell, But It can't.

Comment: Raycasts only hit colliders, not gameobjects. Do your gameobjects have 2D colliders?

Comment: @UnholySheep Yes, they have box collider 2ds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that the objects you want to detect are on layer 9, but you are only testing layer 8 (1 << 8), so you cannot find those on layer 9, which layer mask should be on (1 << 9).

~Pino